# How to remove an object from an array of objects in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this code:

```
var pinpoints= [ { "top": 50,
                           "left": 161,
                           "width": 52,
                           "height": 37,
                           "text": "Spot 1",
                           "id": "e69213d0-2eef-40fa-a04b-0ed998f9f1f5",
                           "editable": true },
                         { "top": 0,
                           "left": 179,
                           "width": 68,
                           "height": 74,
                           "text": "Spot 2",
                           "id": "e7f44ac5-bcf2-412d-b440-6dbb8b19ffbe",
                           "editable": true } ]
```

How would I be able to remove some an object from the array under `pinpoints`.

Comment: Which object do you want to remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pop()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) to remove the last element of the array, or you can use the [`splice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method to remove a specific element.

For example,

```
pinpoints.splice(1, 1);   // removes element with index 1

pinpoints.splice(3, 10);  // removes ten elements, starting at index 3.
```

Answer (score 2):

grep should work for you too

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `filter()` method to remove elements.  It takes a selector, or a function as input.